Both charge and mass are intrinsic properties of matter. So for the existence of matter, should both mass and charge exist simultaneously?
Recently, I came across a book which stated that

"Mass can exist without charge but Charge cannot exist without mass".

Is this statement really correct? As if we look intrinsically in a matter, we would find the presence of electrons, protons and neutrons. Electrons and protons have both mass and charge while neutron on the other hand has mass and charge exists in a neutron in the form of even smaller fundamental particles that we call "quarks". So if we look at it more precisely we would find that a neutral body does have zero overall sum of charges but still we can't deny the fact that charge still exists in that body, though it's net effect might be zero. Also, Can we conclude that both mass and charge are intrinsic properties of matter which exist simultaneously if there is an existence of matter?
Note:- The modern definition of matter is that it is anything that is made up of fermions - particles with half- integer spin, such as quarks or electrons. The rationale behind this is that the Pauli exclusion principle applies to such particles, which leads to matter having the property of taking up space, one of the parts of the classical definition of matter.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158800/174766

Which book? Which page?

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7905/2451 and links therein.

My knowledge about the Higgs mechanism and the electroweak interaction is limited but maybe you can find some answers there. For color charge, you do not necessarily need mass since gluons (strong interaction bosons) carry color charge and they are massless.

Neutrinos are both massive and neutral and as fundamental as the electron as far as we know.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Does this answer your question? Massless charged particles
